# Configure AdonisJS to listen to HTTPS

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, https, adonis.js

It seems to be an evidence for a lot of people, since I really found nothing about how I can configure an AdonisJS app to listen to HTTPS...

Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

> bootstrap/http.js

Replace Server.listen(Env.get('HOST'), Env.get('PORT')) with the following code.

If your cerificates files are in app/ssl folder, you can do this using,

```
const https = require('https')
const Helpers = use('Helpers')

var certOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(Helpers.appPath() + '/ssl/<you-privatekey.pem>'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(Helpers.appPath() + '/ssl/<your-certificate.pem>'),
}

https
    .createServer(certOptions, Server.handle.bind(Server))
    .listen(Env.get('HOST'), Env.get('PORT'))
```

Comment: and is says https is not defined

Comment: @RishabhGusain add "const https = require('https');" on top of page

Comment: Thanks one more help what should be the path of key and cert? it says key undefined

Comment: thanks dude but now its throwing one more error its saying ERROR : EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0

Comment: what should I change in .env file to achieve https?

Comment: @RishabhGusain HOST=localhost
PORT=443